# How do I autorun an application in a terminal in Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gnome, autorun

I've created a few `autorun` script files on various USB devices that run `bash` scripts when they mount.  These scripts run "in the background", how do I get them to run in a terminal window? (Like the "Application in Terminal" gnome Launcher type.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run them as a two stage process with your "autorun" script calling the second script in a new terminal eg

```
gnome-terminal -e top --title Testing
```

Would run the program "top" in a new gnome terminal window with the title "Testing" You can add additional arguments like setting the geometry to determine the size and location of the window checkout the man page for *gnome-terminal* and the "X" man page for more details

Answer (score 1):

```
xterm -e shellscript.sh
```

or (if `xterm` isn't installed)

```
gnome-terminal -e shellscript.sh
```

or (if you're using kubuntu / kde)

```
konsole -e shellscript.sh
```